# ImportError: cannot import name 'locked_cached_property' from 'flask.helpers'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-babel

I've been trying to run a minimal flask app, just a hello world. I've instantiated Flask and Babel. Yet, I'm getting this error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'locked_cached_property' from 'flask.helpers'

I'm using flask v3.0.0, Flask-Babel 2.0.0 and werkzeug 3.0.1

Here's my code:

```py
# app.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Basic Flask app"""
from flask import Config, Flask, render_template
from flask_babel import Babel

app = Flask(__name__)
babel = Babel(app)
app.config.from_object(Config)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    """Home page route"""
    return render_template("1-index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And:

```py
# config.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Config class"""


class Config(object):
    """Flask configs"""

    LANGUAGES = ["en", "fr"]
    BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE = "en"
    BABEL_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE = "UTC"
```

I've tried various solutions involving cached_property, but I couldn't find any solutions related to locked_cached_property.

Note: One of the project requirements is that I must use flask-babel<3

Comment: What line of your code is triggering the error?

Comment: The babel import line, I've solved it though. I'll post my solution rn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to downgrade my Flask (Flask<3) in order to use Flask-Babel<3.

Answer (score 0):

flask-babel was [patched](https://github.com/python-babel/flask-babel/pull/230) and got it to work by using:

```
flask==3.0.0
flask-babel==4.0.0
werkzeug==3.0.1
```

Also, [flask 3.0.0 Requires Werkzeug >= 3.0.0.](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/changes/#version-3-0-0)

Comment: One of the project requirements was that I must use flask-babel<3. That is why this won't be taken.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same problem by upgrading flask-babel:

```
pip3 install --upgrade flask flask-babel
```

Comment: One of the project requirements was that I must use flask-babel<3. That is why this won't be taken.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. Would you be so kind as to add this information to the conditions of the question?